# jquery select() / window.getSelection only updating after mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textfield that I'm binding a select event to and I'm trying to get the selected text while dragging/selecting and output it's text, the only issue is that the select event doesn't trigger until after I lift the mouse up from selecting the text so the output is blank while I'm selecting.. Is there anyway i can change this?

how I'm handling the event:

```
$('#str_field').select(function(){}

var text =  window.getSelection().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#str_field').mousedown(function(){})
```

And if that isn't what you are looking for, look here:
https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/  I think the answer is there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$("#str_field").mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```